# "App Name" Is No Longer Available - Developer app not released

Tags: ios, ipad, certificate

Afternoon all,

We have a client who recently came via our offices and installed a development version of an app we have been working on for a trip to the States to show his colleagues.

He has just gone to test it and is getting the message that '"App Name" is no longer available"' when he tries to open it. We have tested our development devices and the same build of the app here and everything is working fine.

Is there anything we can try as he does not have access to Xcode for a fresh install of the app?

We have checked the developer certs and provisioning profiles and all seem ok and in date.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use a tool like [Fabric](http://fabric.io) to distrubte beta build or Apple TestFlight!

Comment: Thnkas for that. Not sure why i did think of TestFlight

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727969/appname-is-no-longer-available/66006398#66006398

Answer (score 1):

If you gave it to them via ad hoc or something, the provisioning profile has probably expired so you would need to renew that. This is a similar problem I've met before. For the IPA file providing, you could try to upload your apps to Pgyer or TestFlight and provide the installation link to customer.

Answer (score 0):

Happens when the device time is changed to future year. Eg. current year is 2024 and is changed to 2025 in device's time. Upon tapping an installed application, the user will get above mentioned error.
This issue may be due to expired provisioning profiles or certificates; try updating them or reinstalling the app.