# "AppName" is no longer Available

Tags: ios

I've faced an issues in installing my App on the iPad via the Xcode software without uploading it on the Apple Store. I've noticed that after a couple of days the App stops working and doesn't open and displays a message ("App Name" is no longer Available).
What can be the solution to this problem please? The application is personal as I wish not to upload it on the Apple store.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps installed via xcode are only temporary, I dont know the official lifetime of the app but they aren't production apps.

If you want to keep an app private you need to purchase an enterprise licence and then you can release an app onto the app store privately and you just grant access to the people you want to have access.

See [Apple Developer Enterprise](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't have a paid Apple account membership (~ 99 $) and used the `free provisioning` by using XCode deploy directly into your Apple device, then:
The `free provisioning` profiles are **only valid for one week**.